An unexpected error occurred: Unknow PdfException - when merging two PDF files using iText7
I'm having trouble merging PDF files using iText7 version 8.0.4 and C# Net 8. I keep getting an error message: "An unexpected error occurred: Unknown PdfException."
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Utils;


string path = @"C:\Temp\Test\";
string file1 = $@"{path}The order in which the DB engine executes the query.pdf";
string file2 = $@"{path}sql-for-data-analysis-cheat-sheet-letter.pdf";
string mergeFile = $@"{path}mergeFile.pdf";

try
{
    PdfDocument pdfDoc1 = new(new PdfReader(file1), new PdfWriter(mergeFile));
    PdfDocument pdfDoc2 = new(new PdfReader(file2));

    PdfMerger merger = new(pdfDoc1);

    merger.Merge(pdfDoc2, 1, pdfDoc2.GetNumberOfPages());

    // Close the source PDF documents
    pdfDoc1.Close();
    pdfDoc2.Close();

}
catch (IOException ioEx)
{
    LogError($"IO error occurred: {ioEx.Message}");
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uaEx)
{
    LogError($"Access error occurred: {uaEx.Message}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogError($"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}");
}

static void LogError(string message, string details = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(details))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(details);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}

I used a different library, neevia PDFMerge, to see if there were issues with the PDF, but the merge worked fine.

The error message states:

iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException   HResult=0x80131500
Message=Unknown PdfException.
Source=itext.kernel
...

Inner Exception 1: NotSupportedException: Either com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-adapter or com.itextpdf:bouncy-castle-fips-adapter dependency must be added in order to use BouncyCastleFactoryCreator

Try the following:

Download/install NuGet package: itext7
Download/install NuGet package: itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter (or itext7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter)

Add the following using directives

using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Utils;

public static void MergePDF(List<string> filenames, string outputFilename)
{
    using (PdfDocument pdfDest = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFilename)))
    {
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDest);

        foreach (string fn in filenames)
        {
            using (PdfDocument pdfSource = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fn)))
            {
                merger.Merge(pdfSource, 1, pdfSource.GetNumberOfPages());
            }
        }
    }
}

Resources:

How do I resolve Unknown PdfException when using itext7 in. net maui
Is it possible to merge several pdfs using iText7


Thank you for your answer and for pointing me in the right direction. I was missing the Castle package.
Regards,

If this post resolved your issue, then please click Mark as Answer below the post.
